# GRAFANA ERROR - Failed to evaluate queries and expressions: failed to execute conditions: input data must be a wide series but got type long

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

When I try to create an alarm with Grafana, I get this error if there is no record that will trigger any alarm within the specified time period. If there is even a single value that will trigger the alarm, the problem does not occur.

Also configuration and error handling settings are

[image]

How can i solve this problem, any idea?